Does $\tan(x)$ have a power series that converges on its entire domain?
Does the function $\tan(x)$ have a power series? I think it doesn't, because a power series either converges everywhere, or only on a bounded interval. The domain of $\tan(x)$ is neither of those, it is something similar to $\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Z}$. Am I just misunderstanding something? I would like someone to clarify this matter for me. Also, if it does have a power series, what is a closed-form expression for the power series?

If a power series (around $c$) converges for $x=a$ then it converges for all $x$ with $|x-c|<|a-c|$. So your series would have to converges at all points.

I agree your intuition that there is no single power series converging to $\tan(x)$ for every point , but I have no idea for a proof. Only some functions behave so well that the power series converges everywhere including $\sin(x)$ , $\cos(x)$ and $e^x$ , but $\tan(x)$ seems not to behave well enough for that.

Both $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$ are entire functions, i.e., they can be expressed as power series which converge on all of $\mathbb{C}$. But any zero of $\cos(x)$ translates into a pole of $\tan(z)=\sin(z)/\cos(z)$, and thus precludes $\tan(z)$ as being an entire function.

The question in the title does not match the first sentence, and the respective answers differ (no and yes). <> If the title question was meant, you've answered yourself: A real power series converges in an interval about the center, and the domain of $\tan$ is not an interval.

I recommend looking at the theory of taylor series. First from a real perspective and then complex.

In particular taylor series converge in a disk.

The partial-fraction expansion
$\tan(z)=-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(\dfrac{1}{z+\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2}}+\dfrac{1}{z-\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2}}\right)$
converges for all $z$ including the complex domain, except of course the poles. In the complex domain we are rendering the terms from the simple poles, which then must leave an entire function when subtracted from the tangent. This entire-function difference has odd parity and is bounded  as the imaginary part of $z$ tends to infinity, conditions that guarantee the entire function is zero. What remains are the terms from the simple poles.
For a power series, $\tan(z)$ itself has no clear candidates. But from Euler's Fotmula we may render
$\dfrac{1+i\tan(z)}{1-i\tan(z)}=\dfrac{\cos(z)+i\sin(z)}{\cos(z)-i\sin(z)}=\exp(2iz),$
whereupon the familiar exponential series can be used to obtain $\exp(2iz)$ and the result can be solved for a unique root for $\tan(z)$.

This is not a power series, though.

I thought I had a power series for my second solution but tge previous comment is getting more votes. ¿Qué pasa?

I subed $\frac\pi 4$ in your decompostion a few times. I guess there is a sign problem.

No, an orientation ptoblem. I misread which way the curves approach the asymptotes and thought the residues were +1 instead of -1.

The best answer that is not an answer :)
